# how do I delete allocated memory and still return its value from method

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, c-strings

I have this function as part of a class I am writing:

```
const char* sockets::TCPSocket::doRecv(int flags)
{
    char* incomingDataBuffer = new char [this->bufferSize];
    ssize_t bytesReceived    = recv(this->filedes, incomingDataBuffer, this->bufferSize, flags);

    // TODO set timeout - If no data arrives, the program will just wait here until some data arrives.
    if (bytesReceived == 0 || bytesReceived == -1)
    {
        // TODO error handling
    }

    // TODO avoid memory leak
    // delete[] incomingDataBuffer;
    // incomingDataBuffer = 0;


    return incomingDataBuffer;
}
```

As you can see my issue here is that I need to dynamically allocate the buffer size for my incoming string and I would like to return that value to the user. I do not want to leave it to the user to have to then free that memory as that seems like poor encapsulation.

My instinct is to create a static copy of the incomingDataBuffer c string  and return that to my user. However despite some heavy searching I have been unable to find a common method of doing this which leads me to think I may simply be taking a wrong approach.

Clearly I have other options.

- I could make incomingDataBuffer a class member and then deal with its deletion in the destructor, but this somehow doesn't feel right as it has no other reason to be a class member.
- I figure I could iterate through the array and convert it into a vector which can be returned and converted to a string. But again this doesn't feel quite right as the incomingDataBuffer could in some cases be pretty large and this kind of action could be quite expensive.

Anyway, I guess this must be a common problem with a standard approach, so  what is the correct c++ way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard C++ way would be to use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> sockets::TCPSocket::doRecv(int flags)
{
    std::vector<char> incomingDataBuffer(this->bufferSize);
    ssize_t bytesReceived = recv(this->filedes, 
        &incomingDataBuffer[0], this->bufferSize, flags);

    // TODO set timeout - If no data arrives, 
    // the program will just wait here until some data arrives.
    if (bytesReceived == 0 || bytesReceived == -1)
    {
        // TODO error handling
    }

    // on success, do this so that call site knows how much data
    // there actually is
    incomingDataBuffer.resize(bytesReceived);
    return incomingDataBuffer;
}
```

Since `vector` manages its memory, there is no issue of memory leak here. By returning it, you're just transferring responsibility of memory management to the caller - but the caller doesn't have to do anything special. When the `vector` goes out of scope, the memory is `delete`d automatically.

Comment: Thanks but that leads me to a second question... I really want to return a const char* so that I can cout << my return value, but vector has no defined stream function unlike char[]

Comment: @SamRedway You could use `std::string` instead. `std::string` and `vector<char>` are pretty similar with regards to this problem - both are just dynamic containers of `char` that manage memory for you.

Comment: @SamRedway Or you could do [`cout.write()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) with the `vector`.

Comment: Excellent thanks. I used your code but with return type std::string and just converted the vector<char> v like: std::string result(v.begin(), v.end()) and I have achieved my purpose without fiddling with memory allocation at all.

Comment: @SamRedway Now you're making an unnecessary copy! `recv` directly into the `string`

Comment: Ok.. but here is the crux of the problem the recv function is provided by the posix library and it must take a the given arguments so I cannot pass it a string when it wants a char * , it will take a vector but then I will have to convert that vector back into a string or a char*. I'm fairly new to c++ so I may be making a bit of a meal of this, but could you possibly alter the above answer so that it returns a char* or string? Thanks

Comment: @SamRedway `&str[0]` is a `char*`

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. I use the return type char* and then: return &incomingDataBuffer[0]; I was being particularly obtuse :) this works perfectly

Comment: @SamRedway No! You return the `string`! Otherwise you've got a dangling pointer.

Comment: Actually I did it this way and it worked perfectly. The memory space for the vector is not deallocated. I also ran it with valgrind memcheck tool to make sure it was clean and there are no leaks everything was freed. Does this mean that vector is smart enough to keep the memory space open if a pointer is passed back to main and then free when the main goes out of scope? Might be worth noting I am using g++ -std==c++14

Comment: @SamRedway The issue isn't a leak. The memory definitely gets deallocated. The issue is you are pointing to deallocated memory. The fact that nothing else got written into that space in your test does not mean that it "worked perfectly."

Answer (score 0):

The C++ way would be to use [`std::unique_ptr[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

```
std::unique_ptr<const char[]> sockets::TCPSocket::doRecv(int flags)
{
    std::uniqure_ptr<char[]> incomingDataBuffer(new char [this->bufferSize]);
    ssize_t bytesReceived    = recv(this->filedes, incomingDataBuffer.get(), this->bufferSize, flags);


    return incomingDataBuffer;
}
```

`std::unique_ptr<char[]>` does `delete []` in it's destructor, and returning it from function does no copying of the data (since it is simply *moved*).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `std::vector<char>` instead of the dynamically allocated buffer:

```
std::vector<char> incomingBuffer(this->bufferSize);
ssize_t bytesReceived    = recv(this->filedes, incomingDataBuffer.data(), this->bufferSize, flags);
// Other stuff
return incomingBuffer;
```

This way memory is dynamically free'd once the vector leaves scope on the client side. With C++11 and move semantics, there also will be no expensive copy of the vector. In general, try to avoid explicit new/delete in modern C++, that's what the STL containers are for.

Just for completeness: The other alternative would be to use `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`, but for arrays its syntax is inferior to std::vectors in my opinion.